# Places Check-In Deal Not Showing Up

Tags: facebook, checkin

I made a Check In Deal for my business a few days ago and it was approved. When I check on my or an employees phone to 'check in' to test the deal it does not show up.

If I check from the Facebook App on the iPhone it doesn't show a deal at all, the business shows up but not the deal. 
If I check from the safari app and go to the mobile Facebook page when I click check in it shows the little logo confirming a deal at the location, but once you click it and/or post it no deal shows up to claim.

I had hoped for this deal to be going since the 1st and its now the 4th and I still do not see it. Wondering if anyone had any ideas that might get it to work, or if it just takes time to show up on phones even after its approved.

EDIT: I checked on a Virgin Mobile phone and it showed the "check in' logo but again, nothing once you click it, or check in from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forum is for technical questions regarding Facebook Development, and your question cannot be answered here. If you believe something is wrong, file a bug with Facebook here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Oh, when I searched on the Facebook help it gave me this link. My bad. I will look there. Thanks.